# how do I make next and previous buttons to manipulate div display?

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, click

I need to make a presentation where the content of each page sits within a div. The html would look something like this:

```
<div id="p1" style="display:block;">
 //content goes here
   <div id="nav">
     <img class="imgSwap" id="nextBtn">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="p2" style="display:none;">
 //content goes here
  <div id="nav">
     <img class="imgSwap" id="previousBtn">
     <img class="imgSwap" id="nextBtn">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="p3" style="display:none;">
 //content goes here
   <div id="nav">
      <img class="imgSwap" id="previousBtn">
   </div>
</div>
```

When the next button is pressed, the display of the current div is set to none and the display of the next div is set to block. It would be anywhere between 3 or 7 pages (the exact number is not yet known)
But how do I formulate this in jQuery exactly? I am unsure of how to name my divs and address the numbers in the id.
I do already have the jQuery to address the click event:

```
$(function(){  
    $(".imgSwap").mouseenter(function() {
        this.src =  this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        this.src =  this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
    }).click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
});
```

If this seems a silly way to present information, it is because I am working within a set, protected environment. I can not use iFrames for this, for instance, or a presentation in powerpoint. I would greatly appreciate your take on this. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Is it just that you don't know how to write the jQuery so that it does what you've described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, you would have to change your buttons ID to classes :

```
<img class="imgSwap nextBtn">
<img class="imgSwap previousBtn">
```

And doing the same with the parents would be easier as well :

```
<div class="parent" style="display:block;">
```

And then do :

```
$(function(){  
    $(".imgSwap").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            this.src =  this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            this.src =  this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
        },
        click: function() {
            var direction = $(this).hasClass('nextBtn') ? 'next' : 'prev';
            $(this).closest('.parent').hide()
                   [direction]('.parent').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This checks if the button is a "next" or a "previous" button, and changes to the jQuery methods `next()` and `prev()` accordingly. Hides the current `.parent` and shows the next/previous `.parent`. Now all you have to do is figure out when there are no more `.parent` elements to show (hint: using `length`)

Comment: thanks, this works brilliantly! I just leave out the previous button at the first div and the next button at the last div if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all your page (those with an id 'p#')

Then on your click function, do something like this :

```
var parent = $(this).closest('yourClass')
parent.css('display', 'none');
if(this.id == 'previousBtn'){
    parent.prev('yourClass').css('display', 'block')
else{
    parent.next('yourClass').css('display', 'block')
}
```